# Drupal 7: dynamic elements/tokens (logged in user's name) in basic page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm looking for a simple and clean way to create a basic page that shows something like this:

**Hello $user, your ID: $userid**

$user and $userid should show respective values. I want to achieve this with Drupal 7 without having to:

- enable PHP filter
- hack Drupal core files (like http://drupal.org/node/1073886 would do)
- use unstable modules (if possible)
- create new modules/code (if possible)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by creating a view using Views module:

1. set the logged in user as argument.
2. Then you can add the user name and user id as fields but select not to display them.
3. Add a global text where you can insert the user id and user name values in the text using placeholders.